# How to merge hash results from an API in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am retrieving subscriber information from our email provider's API. They return a hash of 25 subscribers per page. I would like to merge the results from each page into one hash (@members_subs_all). However, while my method returns the @members_subs correctly @members_subs_all does not contain any data.

Is merging the right approach? If so, what am I missing to make this work correctly? If not, what should I do differently?

```
def retrieve_members_info
  @members_subs_all = {}
  pages =* (0..1000)
  pages.each do |i|
    @members_subs = # API returns hash of 25 subscribers per page 
      @members_subs_all.merge(@members_subs)
      break if @members_subs["data"].empty?
  end
  puts "members_subs_all #{@members_subs_all["data"]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `merge!` rather than `merge`. `merge` returns the value of the merged hashes, but doesn't change the hash it's called on. `merge!` returns the value of the merged hashes *and* updates the hash it's called on to that value.

Compare the docs on each:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21

Note also that this is a pattern for naming in Ruby and Ruby libraries:

- `method` returns the value of some change to the caller, but doesn't change the caller's value permanently.
- `method!` returns the value of the change and updates the caller with that value.

(See also `method?` which are predicates that return a truthy value based on whether or not `method` is true of the caller.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I also needed to move the merge! statement to execute after the break.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43615/discussion-between-analyticspierce-and-telemachus)

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_hashs(a,b)
  a.merge(b) {|key, a_v, b_v| merge_hashs(a_v, b_v) }
end
```